# JSliders only sliding halfway

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I have a number JSliders in my application and I'm wondering as to why they only slide to half way.

[image]

```
public class test1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public test1() {
        initComponents();
        jSlider1.setExtent(255);
        jSlider1.setValue(-255);
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                     
private void initComponents() {

    jSlider1 = new javax.swing.JSlider();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}                    

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new test().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

private javax.swing.JSlider jSlider1;                
}
```

Comment: So are we, perhaps you'd consider providing a [**runnable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is **not** a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: updated @MadProgrammer

Comment: Any reason why you're using `setExtent`?

Comment: was looking through the methods and it seemed just as good as setMaximum, however now that I've tried setMaximium I see it works much better as it doesn't stop half way.

Comment: You might also want to use `setMinimum` as you `setValue` call is been set to `0` not `-255` ;)

Comment: switched up all the setValues(); to the default GUI colors that I'm using but thankyou none the less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using setExtent or setMaximum would seem to work the same but setExtent makes it so that the slider only slides half way. The proper code looks like this:

```
public class test1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public test1() {
        initComponents();
        jSlider1.setMaximum(255);
        jSlider1.setValue(-255);
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                     
private void initComponents() {

    jSlider1 = new javax.swing.JSlider();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}                    

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new test().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

private javax.swing.JSlider jSlider1;                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set jslider1.setMinimum(-255) and jslider1.setMaximum(255) if your intention is to create range from -255 to 255.

You can also implement ChangeListener interface and use addChangeListener to add the listener to the slider. You can do something in the method stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) e.g. updating the RGB color.